# Division Triple-faults?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have a small snippet of code in x86 assembler, that divides a number

```
push dword 1193182
;push the argument
mov eax, [ebp+4]
push eax
;divide
pop ebx
pop eax
div ebx
push eax
```

In this case [ebp+4] is equal to 262. However, when I run this snippet, QEMU triple-faults

Comment: Use [the CWD instruction](http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/cwd.htm) before `DIV` (or set `edx` to 0).

Comment: Right that worked thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing EDX with `xor edx, edx` solved the problem